# Tag synonym request: [osx] -> [mac]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Currently, the excerpt for [mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) explicitly mentions OS X (as opposed to older operating systems to the mac). I agree with this definition since in common usage, "Mac" does indeed refer to OS X. But I think that in that case we should make [osx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) be a synonym of [mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac).

Alternatively, if we want to make a stronger distinction between the operating system *family* and the current version, we can leave both tags but explicitly explain in the wiki for [mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) that it refers to the whole family, not just OS X. Additionally, since practically all [mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) questions *are* referring to a game running on OS X, if we do this we should probably change the tag from [mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) to [osx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) on most existing [mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) questions.

Answer (score 3):

[mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) is dead, long live [mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac)!

For now, I've also made a synonym, but that might be a problem once Apple decides to do OS11 or whatnot.

Comment: Hmm, you actually made it the other way around from what I suggested...

Comment: @Oak I thought that was what you suggested in the second half of your question. The Mac family changed so much between OSX and OS9 that I'd be hard pressed to find a question about both... unless it's about the Mac series; then something like `mac-series` might be more clear about your intentions.

Comment: "Carbon" applications are programs that will run on Mac OS 9 through Mac OS X v10.5, so it is possible, but also improbable at this point (most major carbon apps have been fully ported to OS X several years ago).