# Rename [osx] → [mac-os-x]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The tag [osx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) should be renamed to [mac-os-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-x) as that is the proper name of the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of Lion, Apple has actually be leaning heavily on calling it "OS X" instead of "Mac OS X". You can see this branding prominently on the [OS X Lion](http://www.apple.com/macosx/) page.

However, the platform (as opposed to the operating system) is generally called "Mac" both by Apple (e.g. the [Mac App Store](http://www.apple.com/mac/app-store/)) and colloquially (e.g. [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/browse/mac/)). I'd much rather see it synonymized to [mac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) instead of the normative use of one version of the operating system name.

Note [this has come up once before](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/tag-synonym-request-osx-mac) and oddly not completed correctly.